# How to know which form I clicked with button class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I know which form I clicked? Is it possible with a button class instead of buttons with id?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".form-buttons").click(function () {
        //I only want the form which corresponds to the button I clicked
        var formDates = $(form).serialize()
        alert ("You clicked "+formDates)
    })
})
```

```html
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" value="date1" name="name1"/>
    <input type="text" value="date2" name="name2"/>
    <input type="text" value="date3" name="name3"/>
    <button type="button" class="form-button"></button>
</form>
<form id="form2">
    <input type="text" value="date4" name="name1"/>
    <input type="text" value="date5" name="name2"/>
    <input type="text" value="date6" name="name3"/>
    <button type="button" class="form-button"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible using name attributes and it attributes.

Comment: Simpler to use a form submit handler and submit button so user can submit with keyboard also

Comment: ... seeing all this answers really hurts ... there is still something that gets referred to as "DOM Level 0" wich already back than allowed accessing the [`form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement) property of any `HTMLElement` which can be associated with an `HTMLFormElement` ... thus one easily can write `$(".form-buttons").click(function () { const formDates = $(this.form).serialize(); /* ... */ }` or `$(".form-buttons").click(function (evt) { const formDates = $(evt.currentTarget.form).serialize(); /* ... */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes use `class` instead of `id` for similar elements. Please try this.

**Note**: `form-button` is the class name in your HTML and not `form-buttons`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".form-button").click(function () {
        var formDates = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
        alert ("You clicked "+formDates)
    })
})
```

Comment: The Op needs to know which form was clicked and then accordingly will the action be taken. Doesn't make sense. How do you identify using above code if it was the first form or the second?

Comment: `this` keyword will return the button clicked and `closest` method will return the corresponding form element. Actually @silversurfer122 wants to serialize that particular form elements values as per the comment in his code inside the click function.

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal look in jQuery API at what `closest()` does. It's actually a better method than using `parents()` in most situations

Comment: Yess! This that i need, really thank you very much man, thanks!! I wasted a lot of hours. Thanks too to the rest of answers, this answer i wich i need.

Comment: @silversurfer122, Glad I was able to help on this. Can this answer be accepted. Thanks!

Comment: @silversurfer122, If you feel this answer helped solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help the community to keep the focus on unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of the element by using the `this` keyword which refer, in a DOM event, to the cibled element :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".form-buttons").click(function () {
        alert('You clicked the form' + this.parentElement.getAttribute('id'));
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you be looking for

```
$('.form-button').on('click', function () {
    alert($(this).parents('form').attr('id')); // Check the ID of the form clicked
});
```

something Maybe Like mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a few different ways. You can traverse up the DOM and see which form is used or -and this is my favorite- you can submit the form!

**Solution 1: Traversing up the DOM**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".form-button").click(function () {
                var clicked_form = $(this).parent();
                var formDates = clicked_form.serialize(); 
                alert ("You clicked "+formDates);
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1">
        <input type="text" value="date1" name="name1"/>
        <input type="text" value="date2" name="name2"/>
        <input type="text" value="date3" name="name3"/>
        <button type="button" class="form-button"></button>
    </form>
    <form id="form2">
        <input type="text" value="date4" name="name1"/>
        <input type="text" value="date5" name="name2"/>
        <input type="text" value="date6" name="name3"/>
        <button type="button" class="form-button"></button>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Solution 2: Submit the form**

You already are using the form, so why not submit it? Change the buttons to input elements with type submit and intercept the submit event, like this. This is how I think it *should be* done. It is also better for user experience because the user can just submit the form by pressing enter.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("form").on('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();                    
                var formDates = $(this).serialize() 
                alert ("You clicked "+formDates)
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1">
        <input type="text" value="date1" name="name1"/>
        <input type="text" value="date2" name="name2"/>
        <input type="text" value="date3" name="name3"/>
        <input type="submit" class="form-button"></input>
    </form>
    <form id="form2">
        <input type="text" value="date4" name="name1"/>
        <input type="text" value="date5" name="name2"/>
        <input type="text" value="date6" name="name3"/>
        <input type="submit" class="form-button"></input>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle on how I would do it.

https://jsfiddle.net/xtfeugav/

Simple use

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
```

to listen for every submit on all the forms you have. To get the ID of the form you use

```
var formid = $(this).attr('id');
```

I used `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the form don't update the page.

Remember to use `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` on your forms to make this work.

Its a simple code, hope it helps.